# Text colouring in CSS within lists

Tags: css, colors

I'm working on CSS and i have a problem with colouring certain parts of a work. For example:

```
<ul id="nav"><li>cats</li></ul><ul><li>dogs</li></ul>
```

I want to color the part with 'cats'.

I use

```
li#nav{color: green;}
```

to make "cats" green, but it is wrong.

How would that be?

Comment: You need a space between `ul` and `id` in your HTML.

Comment: First off, add a space between ul and `id`. Next, the id is on the `ul` and not li. Since the li is a child, you would target the css as `ul#nav li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting your question correct, then your css was wrong
you need to do this

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li>cats</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>dogs</li>
</ul> 

#nav li {color:green}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem, is as I now understand is, that you want to only color the text and not the dot. For that case this is the solution: 
[image: greencat_blackdot]

**1. So in CSS to achieve green cats and black (default) dot**, as asked: 

[image: greencat_blackdot]

```
/* if you want to style every <li> element that is inside <ul id ='nav'> */

ul#nav li:first-line { 
   color: green; 
}
```

or

```
/* if you want to style every <li> element where the parent is a <ul id='nav'> */

ul#nav > li:first-line { 
   color: green; 
}
```

**2. In case you would like to have green dot and green cat**, then remove :first-line

[image: greencat_greendot]

```
 ul#nav li { 
    color: green; 
 }
```

**3. In case you would like to have red dot and green cat**, then do 

[image: greencat_reddot]

```
ul#nav li {color: red;}
ul#nav li:first-line {color: green}
```

Note: you can also just use `#nav li`, instead of `ul#nav li`, but that will color `<li>` tag inside `<ol id='nav'>` and `<menu id='nav'>` tags too.

Note 2: `:first-line` is a CSS Pseudo-element (in case you'd like to search for it)

Comment: So for only a green "cats" it would be the first??

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Clear and simple.